# Identifying crawl bot in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, bots, web-crawler

I have a website which supports browsers with html5 localstorage and JS V8 engine, so basically IE9+ etc. When user browse website with not supported browser, I simply redirect to a new html page, where it suggests to upgrade browser. However, for example Google index this page instead of my main page. In the search, I see only one indexed page and it contains meta tags from page which suggests upgrading browser. How can I using JavaScript identify if it is crawl bot and then not redirect from index page?

Comment: you can do this inside your .htaccess and robot.txt files

Comment: Most crawl bots will not run your javascript at all.  They will just see the HTML page as served from the web server.

Comment: Pastor Bones- I am using NodeJS, so I cannot use .htaccess. jfriend00- but I redirect it using JavaScript function window.location . So why it indexes this page?

Comment: @jfriend00 It is not the 90's anymore, bots run JS.

Comment: @epascarello - please point me to a reference that says all or even most bots run JS and will index JS-generated content, will follow JS redirections, etc...

Comment: Bots may run js, but it doesn't mean they index js content... From my testing and the testing of others, a local document.write of content will be indexed but nothing in a remote js will be.